# How do I see what build is running on TFS 2010 Build Agents

Tags: .net

We are seeing a lot of queuing on our build agents and I am looking for a way to see guilty builds.  Anyone know of an out of the box way to do this?  I would imagine that I can write a report that looks at this or that I could use the TFS API to get this information, but this feels like something that should be available out of the box.  Anyone know of a way to get this information?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by guilty builds. If you could, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

See `Build Controller` status. It shows build status of all build agents.